# Microsoft Access Search Using A Different Column

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I have a ComboBox that has columns: Name, Nickname, and Code in it.  Currently, it is set up to search based on Name as the user types in the ComboBox when the user would prefer to type the Code instead.  Is there a way to set it up so the ComboBox displays like it is originally set up while allowing the user to search using the Code column?  I know that I can easily put the Code column in front of the Name column, but the user would like to keep the format the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: No. A combo box control will always search (autocomplete) the displayed value, which will be the first row source column with a non-zero width. The only way to achieve what you want would be to have two controls. You could have a combo box with Code as the first column followed by Name and Nickname, and then have a locked text box with `Control Source` set to `=myCombo.Column(1)`

Comment: That's a bummer that I can't have it work and look the way the user want it to.  Thank you for the answer though.